# Duplicating pagination on second page

Tags: pagination

Been trying to get this to work and I can get it to show the pagination links but it just duplicates the content from the first page again on page two, can't figure out why?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="posts">
        <?php query_posts('showposts=10&paged=' . get_query_var('paged'));?>
        <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=12' ); ?>
        <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'partials/loop', 'archive' ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div><!-- /posts -->
        </div><!-- /row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /large-10 -->
    <div class="large-2 show-for-large-up columns"></div>
    <div class="large-10 medium-12 small-12 columns">
        <?php if (function_exists('joints_page_navi')) { ?>
        <?php joints_page_navi(); ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <nav class="wp-prev-next">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li class="prev-link"><?php next_posts_link(__('&laquo; Older Entries', "jointstheme")) ?></li>
                <li class="next-link"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer Entries &raquo;', "jointstheme")) ?></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /row -->
```

Comment: you're creating a new query with no pagination parameter: `$the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=12' );`. that said, you should be using [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and not modifying the query in the template, and certainly not using `query_posts`.

Comment: In which template are you doing this

Comment: I'm using the JointsWP Foundation 5 theme http://jointswp.com/

Comment: doh, it's a template page that displays news posts for all post type post categories. The query posts line at the top I think I got confused when reading how to do this somewhere else and I just pasted it in to see if it would work.

Comment: You should use `pre_get_posts` to modify the main query, rather than discarding it and creating a new one

Answer (score -1):

I found [this article](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/04/19/paging-and-custom-wordpress-loops/) and got it to work

```
    <div class="posts">
    <?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=16&paged=' . $paged );
    ?>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/loop', 'archive' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div><!-- /posts -->
    </div><!-- /row -->
</div>
<!-- /large-10 -->
<div class="large-2 show-for-large-up columns"></div>
<div class="large-10 medium-12 small-12 columns">
    <?php
    next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
    previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
    ?>
    </div><!-- /10 columns -->
    <?php
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
    <?php else:  ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- /row -->
</section>
<!-- end Posts Section -->
```

the above works but if I out in a link to page navi plugin like:

```
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
```

then I get nothing same if I put in a link to the previous page navigation code?

```
    <?php if (function_exists('joints_page_navi')) { ?>
<?php joints_page_navi(); ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<nav class="wp-prev-next">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li class="prev-link"><?php next_posts_link(__('&laquo; Older Entries', "jointstheme")) ?></li>
        <li class="next-link"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer Entries &raquo;', "jointstheme")) ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please do not post lone links as answer. Answers should never rely on external links. Please file an [edit] and add all relevant info directly to your answer, keeping the link only as reference and credit. BTW, the code in that link is useless as id does exactly the same as `query_posts`. You should never nullify the main query

Comment: Sorry, what should I do instead?

Comment: Check the codex page for `next_posts_link()`. There is a nice example with a custom query :-)

Comment: I edited my answer, it works with the code in the example but when I try to add either the pagenav plugin code or the original them code back instead of "next_posts_link" etc then nothing shows up?